# Flask: Get the function within the before_request

Tags: python, api, flask, scope, decorator

I want to se a session scope from within a before_request function, so it would act like a `yield` or a decorator callback:

```
@contextmanager
def db_session():
    """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        session.rollback()
        raise
```

```
        with db_session() as session:
            SessionContainer.set_session(session)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

The proper way for that would be to create a decorator that I'll set on each function in the main/blueprint file,

But as I want to have this one for *all* APIs, I'm looking for a way to register a decorator as a before_request for Flask.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

With `before_request` and `teardown_request` hooks I think you can do that. You will use these hooks with the `db_session` context manager you given.
Here is an example:

```
from flask import Flask, g
from contextlib import contextmanager

app = Flask(__name__)

@contextmanager
def db_session():
    """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()

@app.before_request
def setup_db_session():
    g.db_session = db_session()
    g.db_session.__enter__()

@app.teardown_request
def teardown_db_session(exception=None):
    if hasattr(g, 'db_session'):
        g.db_session.__exit__(exception, None, None)
```

Then for each of your API route you do this:

```
@app.route('/api/some_route')
def some_route():
    session = g.db_session . Don't I need to do a with db_session in order to have the __enter__ work
```

This should work

Comment: Thank you!! Don't I need to do a `with db_session` in order to have the `__enter__` work?

Comment: Not necessary, since we are in Flask it can have unexpected consequence